# Htmldocument Load Returns Null

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

This Code works for other sites but when I give way:"http://www.aedn.org/page/1" loads null.Can you help me please.

```
        string Way = Url + PageNumber.ToString();

        HtmlWeb Source = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument Doc = Source.Load(Way);

        List<Movie> MovieList = new List<Movie>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the URL you are using is redirecting to another URL using an HTTP 302 response header - the browser does the redirect for you, but HtmlAgilityPack will not.

Subsequent requests will then work because the response includes a cookie.

You can verify this e.g. using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) in a new incognito browser window.

Answer (score 0):

as we know,the html page may be has different encoding.
so，you can use the C# class WebClient get the html source
and then use htmlagilitypack to resolve the html source.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "UTF-8");
byte[] b = webClient.DownloadData(url);    
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
HtmlDocument Doc = new HtmlDocument();
Doc.load(ms,"UTF-8");
```